# how to display the data of array in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/oxRwYM

HI
I am trying to display data of array in list. I am getting undefined error why ?

here is my code
http://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/oxRwYM

```
var stations = [
  {call:'station one',frequency:'000'},
  {call:'station two',frequency:'001'}
]; 
class App extends React.Component {

  render (){
    var stationComponents = this.props.name.map(function(station) {
            return <div className="station">{station.call}</div>;
        });
        return <div>{stationComponents}</div>;
  }
   handleClick(e){
     alert('--')
   } 

}


React.render(<App name='{stations}'>ssssss</App>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Remove `'`, should be `<App name={ stations }>ssssss</App>`

Comment: thanks got the solutuion ..any react js good tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't wrap props in quotes, as that turns them into a string literal. You're getting an undefined error because you're effectively trying to call `map()` on the string `"{stations}"`, rather than your stations object.

Replace `<App name='{stations}'>ssssss</App>` with `<App name={stations}>ssssss</App>`.